# I need to take a string and output the word that occurs most within the string

Tags: java

I believe that I have the correct code in order to keep going to the next word in the string, however, I am really struggling with how I am supposed to add the most used word into maxW. I also am confused about the maxCnt, will I need to create a whole separate loop just to return the maxCnt?

My professor mentioned using an if statement to compare maxW and maxCnt, but I honestly do not know where to start with implementing that.

```java
String getMode() {
        String tmp = "";
        for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
            if(s.charAt(i)>64 && s.charAt(i)<=122 || s.charAt(i)==32){
                tmp = tmp+s.charAt(i);
                s = tmp;
            }
        }
        String maxW = "";
        int maxCnt = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
            int p =s.indexOf(" ",i);
            int cnt = 1;
            String w = s.substring(i,p);
            i = p;
            for (int j=p+1; j<s.length(); j++) {
                int p1 = s.indexOf(" ",j);
                String w1 = s.substring(j,p1);
                if(w.equalsIgnoreCase(w1))
                    cnt++;
                j = p1;
                maxW = w+s.substring(j,p1);
            }

        }
        return maxW;
    }
```

Everything that I have tried results in a String out of range error code at:

(String.java:1967)
(Hw9.java:36)
(Hw9.java:64)

This is an example of what the result should be: If s =   "You are braver than you believe, and stronger than you seem, and smarter than you think.", this method will return "You".

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: How locked into this implementation are you?  A much cleaner way to do this would be to just build a word-frequency `HashMap`.

Comment: Are you permitted to use maps?  It would be very easy to do it that way.

Comment: I’m very new to coding (about 3 months), and this class is starting from very basics and moving forward. 

We just now got into for and while loops, so all we are permitted to use in this project are mainly for loops (he hasn’t really gotten into while loops yet).

Comment: Some advice: Use good, relevant variable names. `s`, `p`, `p1` are really bad names for anyone looking at your code. Even you, if you go back to look at this in a couple weeks. Even `cnt` and `maxW` are pretty bad. Just spell the whole thing out. I can't tell what's going on without really studying the code or pasting it into a document and compiling myself. As for lines like `s.charAt(i) == 32`, you can just use the char value, e.g. `s.charAt(i) == ' '`. That's the space character in single quotes.

Comment: I have two suggestions: 1. Step back from the code and describe the steps you need to take to solve the task **in word**. Then compare your verbal description to your current code. How closely do they match? Figure out how  you can make them match more closely. 2. Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for some tips about how to debug your code.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider thank you for the input, I will definitely remember to be more specific in the future. I have been so focused on getting the assignments finished I haven't really thought about being able to go back and look at them in the future and understand what is going on, let alone have someone else help me with it.

Comment: I made that loop in the attempt to take out all of the special characters in the sentence and just leave the sentence with words and spaces so that when figuring out how many times the word shows up in the string it will not be missing out on words that have, lets say a comma by it. Also, I did not provide the rest of my code but it asks the user to input a sentence and then that sentence in designated to String s.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use maps, then perhaps you could use two parallel lists.  One for words and one for count.  Search each word in the String list.  If you find it, increment its corresponding count list entry by 1.  If you don't find it, add it to the list and set the appropriate count entry to 1.

Once you get done building your lists, then find the index of the max count and use that to index into the word list to get the word that occurred most often.

Keep in mind that for some data sets (sentences) there could be a multi-way tie.

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code with your example sentence.

Using the string you supplied, `s` has a single character, `Y`. The reason for that is the loop only executes once.

As soon as you set `s = tmp` inside the loop, the length of `s` is now 1, so the loop immediately exits after one iteration.

I'd recommend doing this piece by piece. Break the problem down into chunks, and tackle those one-by-one. Use a debugger or, if you're not comfortable with that yet, make liberal use of `System.out.println()`.

Comment: Regarding the debugging option, I don't know what IDE you use, but IntelliJ community edition is free, and I'm pretty sure you can get a free license for the Ultimate edition as a student . There's good documentation here on how to use the debugger. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html

Comment: Yep, they're still doing it: https://www.jetbrains.com/student/

Answer (score 0):

Here's some ways of counting words mentioned in comments in code form...since it's helpful to see it in code form sometimes:

```
//The map easy way:
Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
if (!counts.containsKey("word")) {
    counts.put("word", 0);
}
counts.put("word", counts.get("word") + 1);

//The double array way (dirty):
int wordsAddedCount = 0;
boolean wordFound = false;
String[] wordsList = new String[500];//assumes max of 500 different words
Integer[] counts2 = new Integer[500];
for (int i = 0; i < wordsAddedCount; i++) {
    if ("word".equals(wordsList[i])) {
        wordFound = true;
        counts2[i]++;
        break;
    }
}
if (!wordFound) {
    wordsList[wordsAddedCount] = "word";
    counts2[wordsAddedCount++] = 1;
}
```

Comment: This can be simplified using Map.getOrDefault since Java 8 - `counts.put("word", counts.getOrDefault("word", 0) + 1);` and no need to initialise first. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-

Comment: You might need to use `.equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `.equals` depending on how you're counting words.

Comment: Alternatively, you can write `word = word.toLowerCase();` before doing `.equals(...)` or using the word as a map key.

Comment: You may as well use the map features designed for this.  `count.compute(w.toLowerCase(), (k, v) -> v == null ? 1
         : ++v)`;